# How do I say “that” with a noun that isn’t neuter?

Tags: gender, article, demonstrative-pronoun

This question is about *that* and *the*. The sentence

> Ist das Geschenk für mich?

means both of the following:

> Is the gift for me?
>   Is that gift for me?

My confusion is that *that* is *das* and *the* is also *das* if the noun is neuter.

So now I wish to translate:

> Is that cup for me?

where *Tasse* is feminine? Can the following be correct?

> Ist das Tasse für mich?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to say *"that object"* then you need to match gender and case. Correct would be

> Ist die Tasse für mich?

or more generally if you just want to say *"that"*

> Ist das für mich?

Or you can combine the two usages

> Ist das die Tasse für mich?

Comment: *Ist das meine Tasse?*

Comment: @PiedPiper: You're right. I totally missed that possible meaning.

Comment: So just for my own pedantic confirmation - saying `Ist die für mich` (or `Ist der für mich` for say `der Bleistift`) is *not* correct and would sound clunky/weird?

Comment: @BruceWayne "Ist die für mich?" works too if the context is clear: if it's obvious you mean "die Tasse" and not "der Becher" or "das Getränk"

Answer (score 12):

The problem you might have is that *das* is both an *article* (translating to **the**) and a *pronoun* (**this**).

So

> Ist das das Geschenk für mich?

(stylistically not exactly elegant) translates to

> Is this the gift for me?

and

> Ist das Geschenk für mich?

Can both mean

> Is this gift for me?

or

> Is the gift for me?

You can work around the ambiguity by using "dieses" which is clearly a pronoun and translates to "this":

> Ist dieses Geschenk für mich?

With regards to other genders than neuter, you use "der" and "die" like in

> Ist der Schuh für mich?
>
> Ist die Tasse für mich?

And you can also extend this with a demonstrative pronoun and end up like

> Ist das der Schuh für mich?
>
> Ist das die Tasse für mich?

Comment: Why not: "Ist das Geschenk für mich?" --> "Is *that* gift for me"?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis There is some overlap in meaning. Yes, you can translate "dieser" with "this" and "das" with "that", but that doesn't mean you never could translate "das" with "this". (But it's subtle, and that's what makes it difficult to grasp. Things like that still give me away as a foreigner while typing English.)

Comment: @MrLister: I don't think there is a big or even subtle difference between English and German in this respect (nor between those two and, say, Dutch, for what it's worth).