# Using the neutral pronoun to refer to other genders?

Tags: pronoun

I’m rather confused by this. When referring to objects/people, which demonstrative pronoun are you supposed to use? The one that corresponds to the gender, or the neutral pronoun?

Example:

> Wessen Tasse ist **die**? **Die** ist meine Tasse.

or

> Wessen Tasse ist **das**? **Das** ist meine Tasse.

Comment: Das hatten wir doch schon mal! War das nicht sogar auch mit einer Tasse? https://german.stackexchange.com/q/41983/266

Comment: No, that's not about the same question. But https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8045/er-sie-es-versus-das?rq=1 is a duplicate.