# Use of das vs die in a sentence

Tags: article, grammatical-number, relative-pronoun, demonstrative-pronoun

A german friend of mine wrote simple sentence today "**Das** sind beides schöne Akzente", to which I asked her, shouldn't it be "***Die*** sind beide schöne Akzente"? She told me my version sounded wrong but she couldn't tell me why and provided a few more examples where I would have also said "die" instead of "das".

I thought I should use die as it is the plural article and in these instances we are talking about a plural.  I would like to understand why "Das" is correct here instead of "die".  Here are a few more examples:

Das sind große Hunde
Das sind blöde Touristen.
Das sind viele Mädchen

Comment: Alternatively you can also use "Dies" 

Comment: [Related question, "How do I say “that” with a noun that isn’t neuter?"](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/41983/19081)

Comment: Und auch in Einzahl geschlechtsagnostisch: Das ist ein großer Hund (m.)/eine kleine Katze(f.)/ein hübsches Mädchen(s.).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Das** may look like an article meaning *the* in this context - But it isn't.

*Der, die, das* can actually cover three functions:

1. Article - That is what you seem to be concentrating on
2. Relative Pronoun - translates to *which* or *that* in English, used as a  subject of a relative clause
3. Demonstrative Pronoun - translates to *that* or *this*. This is what we have here.

If a demonstrative pronoun is used do predicatively denote something using "sein" (like in "This is a green house") the pronoun is normally *not flexed* and instead used in nominative singular neuter, even if it relates to something that is not neuter, not singular, or both:

> Wer ist das? Das ist seine neue Freundin.
>
> Wer ist das? Das sind seine Kinder.
>
> Wer ist das? Das sind ihre Männer.

Comment: So what about ‘that blue dog’? Is it ‘das blaue Hund’?

Answer (score 5):

> Das sind große Hunde. Das sind blöde Touristen. Das sind viele Mädchen.
>
> Es sind große Hunde. Das sind große Hunde. Dies sind große Hunde.

*Es*, *das*, *dies* are all the subject, with no, a small and a big pointing finger at the large dogs. The reason why *das* and *dies* are singular is because *es* is strictly singular, too, and they replace an *es* here.

You **could** use the plural, but then you aren't referring to *große Hunde* any more but to arbitrary things or persons from a previous sentence.

> Kennst du die Hansen-Brüder? – Ja, die sind große Hunde. Alle beide.

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate a little more?  I feel like I am on the cusp of understanding but still didn't quite get it.  Specifically to me, I would have also thought es is incorrect.

Comment: The important part you miss, I think, is, *das* isn't an article to *große Hunde*. You can easily spot this because the predicate *sind* is between them. Instead, *das* is the subject and *große Hunde* is an articleless *Prädikativ* (a "nominative object"). That's why they don't have to agree on number and gender.

Comment: Under what conditions can you tell that it shouldn't have an article as opposed to when it should?

Comment: Oh, you got me wrong. Consider *Das sind die großen Hunde.* Here's the *die* you are missing so badly. This *die* is an article to *große Hunde*.

Comment: Ok.  It still confuses me but I get the point you are making that in the sentence examples das is not the article associated with nominative objects. I still don't get __why__, that is, I don't get why if we have articles, we would choose to not use them in a sentence to refer to something and instead opt to use a singular das, es or dies, but perhaps I need some time to think about it first.  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: ***Who's** making all that noise? – **It's** large dogs.*

Answer (score 1):

"Das" in this context isn't an article, it's demonstrative pronoun, your "pointing" to e.g. the "big dogs". It can be compared to the english "this/these/that/those".